# How do I use an image transition filter in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, core-image

Having followed a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5) on Ray Wenderlich's site with success, I decided to try and manipulate what I learned and apply it towards a CITransition, particularly CIDissolveTransition.  However, I can't seem to get the image to appear even after cross-referencing what I've learned against Apple's own filter documentation (which, I gotta say, are dated and incredibly difficult to adapt outside of their own convoluted examples).  Here is what I have so far:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:image2Path];
CIContext *context;
CIFilter *filter;
CIImage *beginImage, *targetImage;
UIImageView *mainImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self addSubview:mainImage];

beginImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url];
targetImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url2];

if(context == nil)
{
  NSLog(@"Creating Context");
  context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
}
if(filter == nil) {
  NSLog(@"Creating filter");
  filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDissolveTransition" keysAndValues:@"inputImage",   beginImage, @"inputTargetImage", targetImage, @"inputTime", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil];
}

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

[mainImage setImage:newImg];
```

All I've been getting is a black screen where mainImage should be displaying.  The ultimate goal is to be able to cycle through a sequence of images with this dissolve effect using a slider (which I am only assuming will work), but I can't even get this static image to display.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call to filterWithName:keysAndValues: is returning nil because iOS doesn't know how to make a CIDossolveTransition filter.
Core Image for iOS doesn't support all the filters that Core image for Mac OS does.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756311/1313031)

You can read [Apple's Core image Filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) reference and see which filters are supported in iOS, but the bad news is that transitions didn't make the cut for iOS 5.  The only filter available in iOS 5 that deals with compositing is CISourceOverCompositing, which probably isn't very interesting to you.

Comment: Oh, man.  Can't believe I missed that.  That just added a pretty large hurdle to this project.  I'm assuming my next best solution would be to manually manipulate my images' pixel data.  This seems pretty challenging.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is no longer true. Documentation currently states "Available in OS X v10.4 and later and in iOS 6.0 and later."

Answer (score 1):

The Apple WWDC 2014 session  "Advances in Core Image" listed 115 CIFilters available in iOS. The CIDissolveTransition is listed as supported as of 2014.  See session 514 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/514/
Try it again !

Answer (score 0):

As Jay mentioned in his answer, iOS doesn't support transitions.  However, I found and edited a script that grabs the pixel values of two images and returns a cross of the two based on a percentage.  Here's the method:

```
- (UIImage*)morphImage:(UIImage*)img1
             withImage:(UIImage*)img2
             withValue:(float)val
{  
CGImageRef sourceImage = img1.CGImage;
CGImageRef sourceImage2 = img2.CGImage;

CFDataRef theData;
theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage));
CFDataRef theData2;
theData2 = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage2));

UInt8 *pixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theData);
UInt8 *pixelData2 = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theData2);

int dataLength = CFDataGetLength(theData);

//color byte increments
int red = 0;
int green = 1;
int blue = 2;
//temporary rgb values for both images
int r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2;
//fake slider value
for (int index = 0; index < dataLength; index += 4) {
r1 = pixelData[index + red];
g1 = pixelData[index + green];
b1 = pixelData[index + blue];
r2 = pixelData2[index + red];
g2 = pixelData2[index + green];
b2 = pixelData2[index + blue];

pixelData[index + red] += (r2 - r1) * val;
pixelData[index + green] += (g2 - g1) * val;
pixelData[index + blue] += (b2 - b1) * val;
}

CGContextRef context;
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
                              CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage),
                              CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage),
                              8,
                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow(sourceImage),
                              CGImageGetColorSpace(sourceImage),
                              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];

CGContextRelease(context);
CFRelease(theData);
CGImageRelease(newCGImage);

return newImage;
```

}

I haven't tested it on a device, but it runs pretty smooth on the simulator when cycling through 6 to 10 200x200 images using a slider.  I imagine it could be more efficient by extracting the image pixel data beforehand.